# A module of helper functions: tree shaking and testable (mocking, spying, etc)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tree-shaking

Say you have a module of a bunch of helper functions. In some projects one may well only require a single function. You also want your module easily testable, e.g. users should be able to mock functions without having to resort to extra mocking libraries. Please see the two scenarios below.

**Testable**

```js
// code.js

export const namespace = {
 a() {...},
 b() {this.a();},
 c()
};
```

```js
// user.js

const {namespace} = require("./code.js");

export function userFn() {
 namespace.b();
}

// ===> Everything in code.js will be bundled. :(
```

```js
// test.js

const {namespace} = require("./code.js");
const {userFn} = require("user.js");

spyOn(namespace.b)

userFn();

assert.equal(namespaced.b.called, 1);
```

**Tree shaking**

```js
// code.js

export function a() {...}

export function b() {a()}

export function c() {}
```

```js
// user.js

import {b} from "./code.js";

function userFn() {b();}

//Function "c" from code.js will not be bundled.
```

```js
// test.js

// ===> You only really need to know that "b" was called. How to test that? :(
```

Can we have modules of helper functions that are testable and for which tree shaking works - preferably without requiring users to have an extra testing library or so?

Also, please yell at me if there are mistakes in my scenarios.